# Symfony cant keep LDAP connection

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

In my security.yaml i have this one :

```
 providers:
        ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: 'DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM'
                search_dn: 'DOMAIN\ADMIN'            
                search_password: 'PASSWORD'
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: sAMAccountName

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: ldap
            form_login_ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                login_path: app_login
                check_path : app_login
                dn_string: 'DOMAIN\{user_identifier}'
                enable_csrf: true
                username_parameter: login[username]
                password_parameter: login[password]
            logout:
                path: "logout"
```

And, i can login with my LDAP's account

But, when i try to retrieve account's attributes in my controller, i have this message that says :

```
Query execution is not possible without binding the connection first.
```

My controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap;


class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/home', name: 'app_home')]
    public function index(Request $request, Ldap $ldap): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
  $user = $this->getUser()->getUserIdentifier();
        $query = $ldap->query('dc=doadei,dc=wan', '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=' . $user . '))');
        $result = $query->execute()->toArray();
        dump($result);
   
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I dont understand why Symfony dont keep alive my LDAP connection.

I try to connect in the controller with those lines and thats works :

```
      $ldap = Ldap::create('my_ldap', [
                'host' => 'DOMAIN.COM',
                "port" => 389,
                'encryption' => 'none',
                'version' => 3,
                'debug' => true,
                "referrals" => false
            ]);
        $ldap->bind("DOMAIN\ADMIN", "PASSWORD");

        $query = $ldap->query('dc=DOMAIN,dc=COM', '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=' . $user . '))');
        $result = $query->execute()->toArray();
        dump($result);
```

And if i check the :

```
        dump($ldap->getEntryManager());
```

The result :

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\EntryManager {#545 ▼
  -connection: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Connection {#548 ▼
    #config: array:8 [▼
      "host" => "DOMAIN.COM"
      "version" => 3
      "encryption" => "none"
      "port" => 389
      "connection_string" => "ldap://DOMAIN.COM:389"
      "debug" => false
      "referrals" => false
      "options" => array:3 [▶]
    ]
    -bound: false
    -connection: null
  }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the `$ldap` instance that's initialized by the authentication provider is not the same one that you get via dependency injection into your controller, which is uninitialized and not bound. If you want to "reuse" it then you have to ask for it from the authentication provider. But the better option would be to initialize it in your own service container for reusability.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest me to create a service under App\Services and call it whenever I want ?